# How to select 2 highest marks from each groupcode for each student in MySQL 57?

Tags: mysql, sql

Values in my Table.

[image]

Now, expected results
For example, if I choose to pick 2 highest marks in groupcode = 1, I expect to see the following

[image]

**my query**

```
SELECT marks FROM person WHERE groupCode = 1 ORDER BY marks DESC LIMIT 2;
```

getting only the results for `Quigsley Kos groupCode` 1 with marks 69 and 30;

Someone to help on this please.

Comment: Hi. Please [use text, not images/links, for text (including code, tables & ERDs)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use an image only for convenience to supplement text and/or for what can't be given in text. Also please read & act on [mcve].

Comment: @DineshDB, thank you for editing the post. I am first timer here.

Comment: @kibikawanjala, Welcome to Stack overflow...!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT `sn`, `admno`, `studname`, `fclass`, `groupcode`, `subjectcode`, `marks`
FROM
(
SELECT `sn`, `admno`, `studname`, `fclass`, `groupcode`, `subjectcode`, `marks`,
        CASE WHEN @group = T.groupcode AND @studname = T.studname
        THEN @row:=@row+1
        ELSE
             @row:=1
        END AS rownum,
        @group:=T.groupcode AS Vargroupcode,
        @studName:= T.studname
FROM TableA T,(SELECT @group:=null,@row:=0) R
ORDER BY groupcode,studname
) T1
WHERE rownum<=2
```

**Demo**

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/65760b/1

Comment: Reading & updating a variable in a select statement is undefined behaviour. Order by without limit in a subquery has no effect.

Comment: @Jay Shankar Gupta, sir, many thanks, that was very fast. However, I wanted a single query that gives the highest marks in each groupcode for every student; so like groupcode = 2; I expected 12 rows because they are 6 students but I only have 10 rows. Remember not the best in groupCode but highest marks in each groupcode for each student. A little twisting of your code will give the desired results.

Comment: @Jay, thank you so much; it is now whistling through like nobody's business! 1 more last bother, suppose I want to adjust it to give only for one group and not all the groups. For example, groupcode = 1 should give only 12 rows instead of filtering for every group. Cheers!

Comment: You can just add `AND groupcode=1` at the end of query

Comment: @JayShankarGupta, thank you; it kicks in again without complaining; however, the query complains when transferred to C#; I will see how to sort this out; meanwhile I am grateful for your assistance.

Comment: Welcome If you got your answer please accept and upvote @kibikawanjala

Comment: Yes, it worked ok and I have even attempted to upvote your answer but I am still new here, just joined today, having 6 reputation points but to upvote I need more than 15; once I get the 15 I will come back here upvote

Comment: Hello, @JayShankarGupta, I will speedily accept; where do I go from here; show me how to accept the answer it is great.

Comment: below down arrow button a tick button will appear just click on that

Comment: @JayShankarGupta, good done. Is it possible to use the same query to get say, the 3rd largest marks in each group for each student;

Comment: just use `rownum=3`

Comment: CAUTION:  To anyone who might use this answer, it sets variable values in one expression and uses them in another.  MySQL does not guarantee the order of evaluation of expressions in a `SELECT`, so this might not work.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, it will help me if you give a suggestion. Otherwise it is working nicely for me. But I will greatly appreciate for an alternative.

Comment: @JayShankarGupta, I mean if you have this, 34, 30, 20, so the 3rd minimum will be 20; rownum = 3 gives the first 3 largest. So, I want only one not the 3. Thank you.

Comment: @JayShankarGupta, it worked out very well. I didn't see the = sign. Thank you.